# Conditionally-fixed Views and Editors in Eclipse RCP Perspective

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, perspective, eclipse-plugin

We have an Eclipse perspective with an editor area in the middle. We're looking for a bit more customization with regards for how we can enable/disable the minimize/maximize controls for an `IFolderLayout`

We're on the Eclipse 3.7 platform, but the most customization we can find is using the `setFixed()` method on the entire `IPageLayout`.

The ability to hide the min/max controls using `setFixed()` is desirable, but we'd like to be able to do it for a particular set of views. **We'd like for the vast majority of our views to be fixed, but a select few should allow for maximizing.**

Is there any way to implement conditional controls for a select few views? The Javadocs for the `IPageLayout`, `IFolderLayout`, and `IViewLayout` don't seem too promising - nor do any perspective/RCP layout guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IViewLayout` has `setCloseable` and `setMoveable` methods which should do what you want.